# Push error when deploying discord bot on Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, discord, bots, push

**could anyone help me, please?**

I know *very little* of programming, still, I managed to create a Discord bot for a server. Initially, it worked perfectly, but one day I couldn't deploy it on Heroku anymore when I made any change on the bot.

Here is the *error message*:

```
$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 24, done.
Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 1.75 KiB | 895.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 19 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.19.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.8
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
remote:        Module installation may take longer for this build
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:
remote:        > node-cron@2.0.3 postinstall /tmp/build_d666c44d/node_modules/node-cron
remote:        > opencollective-postinstall
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: opencollective-postinstall: Permission denied
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
remote:        npm ERR! node-cron@2.0.3 postinstall: `opencollective-postinstall`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the node-cron@2.0.3 postinstall script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Miyop/_logs/2020-11-16T21_23_56_325Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to gale-explorer.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/gale-explorer.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/gale-explorer.git'
```

Could anyone help me with a **detailed step-by-step procedure**?
Thank you so very much.

Comment: "one day I couldn't deploy it on Heroku anymore when I made any change on the bot"—well, what did you change?

Comment: When I make any changes in the bot code, I have to deploy them to Heroku again so it can work. I used to do this every time I added a command or modified an existing one, and it worked well. Now it doesn't work anymore.